# Why length return Int and not Num

Tags: haskell

Is there any reason for restricting `length` function to `Int` and not to `Num` ?

A lot of functions from prelude have the restriction to `Int` type and not to a more generic type / typeclass:

```
:t length
length :: [a] -> Int

:t take
take :: Int -> [a] -> [a]

:t drop
drop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

But there are also more generic functions in Data.List

```
:t genericLength
genericLength :: Num i => [a] -> i

:t genericTake
genericTake :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]

:t genericDrop
genericDrop :: Integral i => i -> [a] -> [a]
```

Why the first ones have the `Int` restrictions and are not defined generic as the second ones ? 
Is there any reason for this `Int` restriction?

Comment: Also see this: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/211053/why-isnt-length-generic-by-default